# Linq to Sql database query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I was creating a method `loginusern()` where Linq checks if password matches login name. Problem is in

```
var password = (from s in DB.Users 
                where s.password == U.name 
                select s).FirstOrDefault();
```

but I can't figure out why....

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    User User = new User();
    User.name = txtLogin.Text;
    User.password = txtPassword.Text;

    loginusern(User);
}

private void  loginusern(User U)
{
    GarageDBEntities DB = new GarageDBEntities();
    var obj = (from s in DB.Users where s.name == U.name select s).Count();

    if (obj == 1)
    {
        var password = (from s in DB.Users where s.password==U.name select s).FirstOrDefault();

        if (password.ToString() == U.password)
        {
            Session["admin"] = U.name;
            Response.Redirect("~/Pages/Account/Admin.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            lblResult.Text = "password is incorect";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lblResult.Text = "password or username is incorect";
    }
}
```

Comment: You should never store plaintext passwords. Instead, one-way hash and salt them, then compare hashed forms of the passwords. The idea is that the plaintext password should not be recoverable without resorting to brute force.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do this:

```
var password = (from s in DB.Users where s.password==U.name select s).FirstOrDefault();
```

you are getting the user, not the password.
Try this:

```
var password = (from s in DB.Users where s.password==U.name select s.password).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Eduardo :)